# Hebrew of the Mishneh Torah

Tags: hebrew, torah-study, rambam

In what type of Hebrew did Rambam write the *Mishneh Torah*?

I just started to learn Biblical Hebrew and when I have learned basics I will start to read Pentateuch in Hebrew with some help The next step will be Rambam. Now, should I also learn Mishnaic Hebrew or Modern Hebrew in order to understand *Mishneh Torah*?

Background: I'm not a Jew but I'm interested in Judaism. I'm pondering on conversion in the future.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya!  Thank you for bringing your question here.  You may also be interested in our 92 questions tagged [tag:gerut-conversion].  I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 4):

Like Tamir Evan said in his comments

In his introduction to Sefer ha-Mitzvot, the Rambam claimed he wrote the Mishneh Torah in the language of the Mishnah( Leshon ha-Mishnah), to ease the readers' understanding.

So the answer would be Mishnaic Hebrew

Comment: I have no idea why this answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Rambam wrote Mishnheh Torah in a Hebrew that is not far off of modern Hebrew, and a good modern dictionary will be invaluable.

It is heavily influenced by Mishnaic Hebrew, and it might be classified by some as "Rabbinic Hebrew", although I'm not sure that's a standard description of his writing.

Comment: There's also a noticeable [Arabic influence](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22899/5).

Comment: In his [introduction to _Sefer ha-Mitzvot_](http://www.daat.ac.il/DAAT/mahshevt/hamitsvot/hakdama1-2.htm), the Rambam claimed he wrote the _Mishneh Torah_ in the language of the Mishnah( _Leshon ha-Mishnah_), to ease the readers' understanding.

Comment: @Tamir Evan, good call. Sounds like an answer. :-)

Comment: Weird about the commentless downvotes.