# Learning to read Mishneh Torah

Tags: hebrew, rambam, mishneh-torah

I have taken a number of classes covering Hebrew grammar and basic vocabulary and my proficiency level is basic but sufficient to navigate the Siddur, and with a dictionary (looking up many words) I can navigate a parasha very slowly.  I would love to reach a level where I could more easily navigate something like Rambam's MT, however, I've  found it difficult to increase my proficiency level beyond my current level.

For those who have experience working with Hebrew texts like the MT, what would be your advice for the learning process to take me from where I am now to where I'd like to be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hebrew of the Mishneh Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27552/hebrew-of-the-mishneh-torah)

Comment: Here's a vowelised text with translation of the Mishneh Torah, it may facilitate your learning: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm

Comment: Famously, the Rosh said that one cannot understand the Rambam's intent without knowing the underlying Gemara. I would suggest starting with something like Mishnah first

Comment: Famously, the Rosh said that one cannot understand the Rambam's intent without knowing the underlying Gemara. I would suggest starting with something like Mishnah first

Answer (score 4):

You could listen to a shiur online where somebody reads and translates the text.

A quick search found [this](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam.asp?tdate=10/21/2020) which reads and explains the daily Rambam MT chapter, loud and clear.

You have a choice of 3 versions, which you can listen to online or download as audio or video. No cost.

<sup>Disclaimer: I know nothing about these shiurim except - from listening to a few seconds - that they are loud and clear and free.</sup>

Comment: This is a very good suggestion and introduces the idea of becoming familiar with how others understand the meaning of the Hebrew texts. But it is important to remember that this type of practice is limited by the level of understanding that the Moreh Shiur has. Part of the mitzvah of Limud HaTorah is continually improving ones reading comprehension both in terms of vocabulary and grammar. It is said that the Vilna Gaon, someone who learned Torah prodigiously, always studied with dictionaries and grammar books at his side. The chiddushim you see with your eyes are unique to your learning.