# Hebrew Dictionary for Mishneh Torah

Tags: product-recommendation, words, hebrew, rambam, mishneh-torah

I’m looking for a dictionary which contains words that one would find in The Rambam’s Mishneh Torah, not Biblical Hebrew. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I would assume Jastrow would have everything.

Comment: Related: "[Hebrew of the Mishneh Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27552/1368)".

Comment: Look for a dictionary on Mishnaic Hebrew.

Comment: This is the best one I know of for all eras of Hebrew: https://archive.org/details/AComprehensiveEtymologicalDictionaryOfTheHebrewLanguageErnestKlein1987OCR

Comment: Wikisource for Hebrew is good too